# Change Sets and too many SOQL statements

Tags: soql, unit-test

I'm at a point where I'm bumping up to a ceiling in the number of SOQL statements during deployment of inbound change sets - I have several VF pages, page controllers, triggers and test classes, and  even though my classes are bulkified, I have about 35 classes, with some tests having intensive update/insert activity.

Is there a way to deploy classes such that all tests don't run?  I heard that deploying from eclipse will do this, but I don't want to "cheat" - I just want to run the classes relevant to what I'm deploying.

Thanks for any help

EDIT:
Per Eric's suggestion, A good example is this; This is a snippet from a VF controller - it executes a possible of four aggregate queries - and I have one of these components for MTQ/QTD/YTD - with tests, that's 24 queries;   I guess ideally, if I could make one aggregate SOQL from two (or even four) that would be ideal, but I don't know if SOQL syntax would support that.

```
if (ExecId == UserInfo.getUserId() || ExecId.length() <= 5) {  // all was implicitly selected
    AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT SUM(TCV_Expected_Revenue__c)  tcvtotal
                                        FROM Opportunity
                                        WHERE
                                        CloseDate >= :begDateMTD AND CloseDate  <= :endDateMTD
                                        AND (StageName LIKE '%Stage 5%' OR StageName LIKE '%Closed - Won %')
                                        AND (Type LIKE '%New Business%' OR Type = 'DNS - New Business (New Customer)')
                                        AND Fiancial_Reporting_Center__c != NULL];
    objTCV = groupedResults[0].get('tcvtotal');
    AggregateResult[] groupedResultsPend = [SELECT SUM(TCV_Expected_Revenue__c)  tcvtotal
                                            FROM Opportunity
                                            WHERE  CloseDate >= :begDateMTD AND CloseDate  <= :endDateMTD
                                            AND (StageName LIKE '%Stage 0%' OR StageName LIKE '%Stage 1%'
                                                    OR StageName LIKE '%Stage 2%' OR StageName LIKE '%Stage 3%'
                                                    OR StageName LIKE '%Stage 4%')
                                            AND (Type LIKE '%New Business%' OR Type = 'DNS - New Business (New Customer)')
                                            AND Fiancial_Reporting_Center__c != NULL];
    objTCVpend = groupedResultsPend[0].get('tcvtotal');
} else {    // its not ALL - so SELECT by vertical mkt manager
    AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT SUM(TCV_Expected_Revenue__c)  tcvtotal
                                        FROM Opportunity
                                        WHERE Fiancial_Reporting_Center__r.Id = :ExecId
                                                AND CloseDate  >= :begDateMTD AND CloseDate  <= :endDateMTD

                                                AND (StageName LIKE '%Stage 5%' OR StageName LIKE '%Closed - Won %')
                                                AND (Type LIKE '%New Business%' OR Type = 'DNS - New Business (New Customer)')];
    objTCV = groupedResults[0].get('tcvtotal');

    AggregateResult[] groupedResultsPend = [SELECT SUM(TCV_Expected_Revenue__c)  tcvtotal
                                            FROM Opportunity
                                            WHERE Fiancial_Reporting_Center__r.Id = :ExecId
                                                    AND CloseDate  >= :begDateMTD AND CloseDate  <= :endDateMTD
                                                    AND (StageName LIKE '%Stage 0%' OR StageName LIKE '%Stage 1%'
                                                            OR StageName LIKE '%Stage 2%' OR StageName LIKE '%Stage 3%'
                                                            OR StageName LIKE '%Stage 4%')
                                                    AND (Type LIKE '%New Business%' OR Type = 'DNS - New Business (New Customer)')];
    objTCVpend = groupedResultsPend[0].get('tcvtotal');
}
```

Comment: This might be something that you can move into a utility class, I don't think it will take a big bite out of your SOQL though

Comment: Something that occurred to me from reading the comments was to just have one test class that tests all three controllers.   That will save save eight SOQL statements.

Answer (score 3):

No, Eclipse can't break the rules for deployments to production, so there really is no such "cheat." You'll need to fix your query problems. The precise details vary, so you may need to contact an expert to help reduce your SOQL usage, but in general, crank up profiling and database logging to the maximum, run your tests, and see which queries are taking the most time/rows/resources, and go from there.

Comment: Yikes - that seems like a big limitation.   If one makes a lot of customizations, and runs tests for each of these   we run into a hard limit - especially with a lot of VF pages....

Comment: @user2223 Not really, SFDC requires these limits because we are all sharing resources..  There is no room for poorly written classes and triggers, just because they are bulkified doesn't mean they are using the best techniques... You should also be exploring Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() methods if you aren't already

Answer (score 0):

No, this is a Salesforce feature that is there for your protection. Your test classes protect you from breaking expected functionality. You will have to optimize either your architecture or the code. Here are some basics to implement to optimize the code itself:

1. Remove all queries from `for` loops.
2. Make sure you have records to act on before you perform your query. In other words, filter your records as thoroughly as possible.

I have found that implementing a trigger handler pattern facilitates adding static `bypassTrigger` flags that could reduce this sort of activity during tests.

Trigger:

```
trigger MyObject on My_Object__c (before insert, before update) //etc.
{
    MyObjectTriggerHandler handle = new MyObjectTriggerHandler(trigger.new, trigger.oldMap);

    if (trigger.isBefore)
    {
        if (trigger.isInsert) handle.beforeInsert();
        if (trigger.isUpdate) handle.beforeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Handler:

```
public with sharing class MyObjectTriggerHandler
{
    // set this to true in tests when you want to turn the whole trigger off
    @TestVisible static Boolean bypassTrigger = false;

    final List<My_Object__c> newRecords;
    final Map<Id, My_Object__c> oldMap;
    public MyObjectTriggerHandler(List<My_Object__c> newRecords, Map<Id, My_Object__c> oldMap)
    {
        this.newRecords = newRecords;
        this.oldMap = oldMap;
    }

    public void beforeInsert()
    {
        if (bypassTrigger) return;

        List<My_Object__c> shouldAct = MyObjectServices.filter1(newRecords, oldMap);
        MyObjectServices.method1(shouldAct); // only pass what you need
    }     

    public void beforeInsert()
    {
        if (bypassTrigger) return;

        List<My_Object__c> shouldAct = MyObjectServices.filter1(newRecords, oldMap);
        MyObjectServices.method1(shouldAct); // only pass what you need
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public with sharing class MyObjectServices
{
    public static List<My_Object__c> filter1(List<My_Object__c> newRecords, Map<Id, My_Object__c> oldMap)
    {
        List<My_Object__c> results = new List<My_Object__c>();
        for (My_Object__c newRecord : newRecords)
        {
            // get as few records as possible
        }
        return results;
    }
    public static void method1(List<My_Object__c> filterResults)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SFDCFox wrote a good answer, but I would like to add..

One thing you need to make sure is that you are using Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest, by doing so it will give the unit test context, so it will ignore any dml outside of your start and stop and will only count what happens in in between your tests.

Comment: Cool.   Thanks everyone!   But - what to keep me from placing the starttest ans stoptest between an arbitrary group of statements that don't do any SOQL at all?

Comment: Review some test classes and post some that you think that may need updating